# w3c validator ignores changes after jQuery & javascript changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, w3c-validation

I have a website that needs to pass every error on W3C Validator. A couple of the errors I have are related with the alt text of the images. I wrote this and added it on the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('img').each(function(){
                var $img = $(this);
                var filename = $img.attr('src');
                $img.attr('alt', filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            });

        });
</script>
```

However, I saw that W3 validator ignores any change I do with javascript and took the HTML page just before the javascript runs. A similar one is when I load a map with JS and the W3 validator sees it as an empty element.

Is there any way to make the validator waits before it checks the page?

Comment: No because the validator is used to validate your HTML. Your HTML should be valid at all times, and certainly _before_ any javascript - this is because people who are less capable and have javascript disabled won't see your changes, so it would just be cheating a validator. Your JS is separate from your HTML. (ALSO: You are already trying to cheat the alt tag by automating the values, but that's not the point - the alt tags are there for accessibility, and allow people with images disabled to see them. The `src` will be there regardless, so there's no point doing it like this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of validating HTML is to ensure that it can be read properly by the browser and other tools (such as web crawlers) and conforms correctly to the HTML specification. By the time your code runs, **that's already happened**, and anything invalid that the browser handles has already been handled, and anything invalid the browser *can't* handle has already prevented the document from being interpreted properly. It's too late at that point to try to retroactively make the HTML valid; it's already been read.

Put it another way: Your `img` *tags* remain invalid, all you're doing is fixing the resulting `img` *elements* the browser created.

The only way to make those `img` *tags* valid is to add the `alt` to them in the HTML file itself, with (as [somethinghere points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433880/w3c-validator-ignores-changes-after-jquery-javascript-changes/35433984#comment58565974_35433984)) useful content rather than simply the source filename.

Comment: Also, the `alt` tags - when used - should actually contain more information than the filename, as thats already available in the `src` attribute anyway.

Comment: @somethinghere: Absolutely.

Comment: Put it another way: the document that is seen by the validator is what you see in the old-school View Source function, not the DOM tree view in the inspector. The validator doesn't have a JavaScript interpreter and so will not evaluate any scripts that appear in the document. Whatever markup gets sent by the server is what the validator gets.

Answer (score 0):

You're editing the dom, the Validator does not check the DOM but only the HTML. You need to add an alt attribute to every pictures yourself.